# Add a slash before double quotes in every tag using php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Got this code and for some reason I cannot add a slash before the double quotes

```
<?php 
$string = '<a href="https://google.com">Link</a>';
$string = addcslashes($string, '"');    
$string = str_replace(array('""', '""'), '"', $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Result

```
<a href="\&quot;https://google.com\&quot;">Link</a>

Converted the &quot; to "
<a href="\"https://google.com\"">Link</a>
```

What I need to achieve is

```
<a href=\"https://google.com\">Link</a>
```

This is My current code for use with json

```
if( have_rows($content_rows) ):
    while(the_flexible_field($content_rows)):
        if( have_rows('questions_&_answer') ): ?>
        <script type="application/ld+json">-->
        {
            "@context":"https://schema.org",
            "@type":"FAQPage",
            "mainEntity":[
        <?php $faqs = get_sub_field('questions_&_answer');
        $rowCount = $hillo;
        $comma = ',';
        $i = 1;
        while ( have_rows('questions_&_answer') ) : the_row();

        $string = get_sub_field('answer', false, false);
        $string = addcslashes($string, '"');    
        $string = str_replace(array('"\"', '\""'), '\"', $string);
        ?>
        {"@type":"Question","name":"<?=get_sub_field('question', false, false)?>","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"<?=$string?>"}}<?=($i < $rowCount) ? $comma : '';?><?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
            ]
        }
        <!--</script>-->
        <?php 
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Just remove `$string = str_replace(array('""', '""'), '"', $string);`

Comment: @u_mulder Hi, still same result <a href="\"https://google.com\"">Link</a>

Comment: Where https://3v4l.org/sgVCv?

Comment: @u_mulder this is your code I'm using but see the screenshot https://prnt.sc/qdl11s

Comment: So, the output is processed as html. What output do you want then?

Comment: And even more - what is the source problem that you try to solve by adding slashes?

Comment: It needs to have the slashes before the double quote for my json schema

Comment: Have you heard about `json_encode`? It will do all the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is super simple. The thing is, you need to escape the backslash too, since if you don't, it will treat your backslash as an escape character for your quote meaning it would replace a quote with a quote!! :-P

Like this:

```
$string = '<a href="https://google.com">Link</a>';  
$string = str_replace('"', '\\"', $string);

echo $string;
```

Which will yield:

```
<a href=\"https://google.com\">Link</a>
```

Check it here https://3v4l.org/c89h8

Comment: Please also explain *why* the extra slash needs to be escaped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is My answer, this is very nerve racking but I finally made it to work

Here is My code

```
if( have_rows($content_rows) ):
    while(the_flexible_field($content_rows)):
        if( have_rows('questions_&_answer') ): ?>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context":"https://schema.org",
            "@type":"FAQPage",
            "mainEntity":[
        <?php $faqs = get_sub_field('questions_&_answer');
        $rowCount = $hillo;
        $comma = ',';
        $i = 1;
        while ( have_rows('questions_&_answer') ) : the_row();
        $parseme = get_sub_field('answer', false, false);
        $hay = json_encode($parseme);           
        ?>
        {"@type":"Question","name":"<?=get_sub_field('question', false, false)?>","acceptedAnswer":{"@type":"Answer","text":"<?=wptexturize($hay)?>"}}<?=($i < $rowCount) ? $comma : '';?><?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
            ]
        }
        </script>
        <?php 
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

What I did was added this under the second while loop

```
$parseme = get_sub_field('answer', false, false);
$hay = json_encode($parseme);
```

and then I used this

```
wptexturize($hay)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a possible alternative, doable with a quick regex, like so:

```
$string = '<a href="https://google.com">Link</a>';    
echo preg_replace('/"/', "\\\"", $string);
/* <a href=\"https://google.com\">Link</a> */
```